# After installing Ubuntu Touch dualboot Recovery is lost

Tags: dual-boot, ubuntu-touch, android

I installed Ubuntu Touch dualboot app by following instructions from the Ubuntu Wiki. 
Installation of UT went fine and I can use the dualboot function properly. However, I see now, my recovery partition is lost. I cannot reboot into the Recovery.

I have tried rebooting into recovery from the bootloader, and also have tried giving the command `adb reboot recovery` . Every time I do that, it boots into the Ubuntu partition instead of the Recovery.

Is there any way I can fix this ? I am using Nexus 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is expected.

Ubuntu Touch, when installed, overwrites your Boot, OS, and Recovery partition.

The dual booter only sacrifices your Recovery partition. There is no way (except with MultiROM) to create two "OS" partitions. It is a quick-n-dirty hack. (See https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/DualBootInstallation)

In other words, you HAVE to give up something to use UT. Recovery or whole system. Following the instructions in the above link, you can find out how to temporarily boot into Recovery mode instead of UT.